# React On Rails gem with Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, rails-api, react-on-rails

I'm trying to run React on top of a Rails API. I created the Rails app with the `--api` flag so I could make it as minimalist as possible and I chose the react_on_rails gem to make React work on top of that, since it seemed to be a nice way to decouple both client and server applications.

I followed the tutorial on the [gem's Github page](https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails) and got everything working but when I try to access the URL `http://localhost:5000/hello_world` after running Foreman I get the following:

```
19:34:58 web.1    | Started GET "/hello_world" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-03-07 19:34:58 +0000
19:34:58 web.1    | Processing by HelloWorldController#index as HTML
19:34:58 web.1    | Completed 204 No Content in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I'm pretty sure the reason why I get this response is because Rails is not going through all the asset pipeline and is not rendering the `index.html.erb` view, because of the API mode.

So my question is, can I make the Rails API work with React, via the react_on_rails gem, just as things are? Or do I need to make changes to the configuration so the Rails app stops working in 'API mode'? Or perhaps I can tweak the gem's configuration to work properly, although I couldn't find anything in the docs.

My `hello_world_controller.rb` controller, auto generated with `rails generate react_on_rails:install` looks like this:

```
class HelloWorldController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @hello_world_props = { name: "Stranger" }
  end
end
```

All help and guidance will be very much appreciated, since I'm not really an expert on any of these tools. Thanks!

Comment: How does your controller look? 204 no content is not really an error, its a success status code saying that besides the status the server responds without any content.

But I assume if you generated the rails app with --api, and then used any of the rails generators to generate the controller, it will not respond to html requests, thus not rendering the index.html.erb

Comment: That makes no sense. You shouldn't be trying to mix `--api` with an app that serves non-API content.

Comment: @meagar yes, I was kinda getting conviced that was the issue because I guess in this case the Rails app is not really behaving as just a an API, since the client code is being processed by webpack and then being rendered by the app

Comment: I think the reason why its not behaving as an Api is that react_on_rails generates a server side view (which i guess then uses some helper to render the react component). 

In an approach where rails is really just providing an api, and all client side logic happens in react, you probably wouldn't need a gem like react_on_rails or react-rails

Comment: @trueunlessfalse that makes total sense. I was going for the approach of having both the server and client code on the same project, but I guess the key thing here is that it's not working because the Rails app is not actually going through the view but instead sending an empty JSON response

Comment: Someone wrote a very nice tutorial about Rails API and react just recently propably will help you with using Rails and react. https://medium.com/superhighfives/a-top-shelf-web-stack-rails-5-api-activeadmin-create-react-app-de5481b7ec0b#.d281agrql

Comment: @Koen dude, thanks a lot! That tutorial looks awesome, I'll be sure to check it out!

Answer (score 0):

React on Rails ultimately serves the webpack bundle through Rails' view layer.  So no it won't work with api-only out the box.